# Is this a reference of an AC/DC REGULATED adaptor?

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc

I need to choose an 230 VAC / 12 VDC converter which is **regulated**, that-is-to-say I need the voltage to be 12 V with a current of 0 to 5 A.

I found this one because it is the cheapest (price really matters) : https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/260/GSM60A-SPEC-1147092.pdf

But I do not see any information regarding its regulation. Is it regulated ? Generally speaking, how do I know in datasheet if an adaptor is regulated or not ?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the datasheet specifications on line and load regulation and voltage tolerance and see if it meets your specific requirements.

The devices in that datasheet sport total voltage tolerance of +/-2.5% to +/-5% depending on model, including line and load regulation. I don't see a temperature dependency specification.

So if you buy a +/-3% 12V model, the average (nominal 12V) output will be between 11.64V and 12.36V at 25°C ambient for all valid combinations of mains input and load. There will be some ripple on top of <100mVp-p under the specified conditions.

Since the input can vary from 80 to 230VAC (or 113 to 370VDC) with the output varying less than +/-1%, obviously it's regulated.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of a fairly tight, symmetrical voltage tolerance that does not vary with load current tells you it's regulated. Also, the fact it has a line and load regulation listed.